# What is the smallest degree that $r(x)$ can take such that it is divisible by $q(x)$?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

[image: Image of question]

I am having trouble figuring out part c of the attached question. At first I thought the smallest degree would be the same as $q(x)$ since we could have $r(x)=q(x)$, but that doesn't work since $q$ has zeroes and is complex which violates the conditions for $r(x)$. I am not really sure how to approach the question, and the previous parts don't seem to give some obvious hint on what to try. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think for c) any constant multiple of q(x) would suffice as an r(x), consequently the minimum degree of r(x) is the degree of q(x).

Comment: But wouldn't a constant multiple of $q(x)$ also have zeroes and still be complex?

Comment: sorry I missed the first sentence. I didn't realize the $x_n$ were 4 times the eighth roots of unity. But the degree of r will at minimum be the degree of q.

Comment: Keep in mind in order for a polynomial to be real, for reach complex root, the complex conjugate must also be a root and they must have the same multiplicity

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow, but how does that help with this question?

Answer (score -1):

We have $x_k=4e^{i2\pi k/8}$ for $k$=0,1,2,...,7. Ignoring the modulus, these are the eighth roots of unity. It can be shown that for a given $x_k$, $\bar{x_k}=x_{8-k}$. The conjugate for a given index $k$ is the x having index $8-k$.

In $q(x)$, the multiplicity of $x_1$ is 5. The conjugate of $x_1$ is $x_7$, by the above, and its multiplicity is two. Since $r(x)$ is a multiple of $q(x)$, we are only allowed to mitigate the discrepancy by multiplying. For $x_7$ to have the same multiplicity as $x_1$, we need to multiply $q(x)$ by  $(x-x_7)^3$.

By this principle,  $r(x)=Aq(x)(x-x_7)^3(x-x_2)^5(x-x_5)$ for some real A. Terms in $x_0$ and $x_4$ can be ignored since they are real.

From this it follows that the order of $r(x)$ is the order of $q(x)$ plus $9$.

Comment: While I understand that what you have done here makes the smallest order of $r(x)$ where $r(x)$ is a real polynomial, this still doesn't address the real factors of $q(x)$, as $x_0=4$, meaning $q(4)=0$, and hence $r(4)=0$. However we are looking for $r(x)$ such that it is non real. Any idea on how to remove these zeroes?

Comment: I think by non-zero here is meant the function is not strictly zero. It has to be. Any polynomial divisible by q will have all the zeroes of q.